Group Policy missing on Windows Server 2022
I have Windows Server 2022.
I need to update a GPO, but the editor is empty.
I did no special modification between yesterday and today.
Can you help?
I tried to run regsvr32 command, but it didn't work.
Local Policy Editor

Why are you providing a screenshot of Local Policy? That is not Group Policy. State what you did, with the steps.
